# WP Cron being triggered but not working as expected

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron

I have created a **WP cron job**, my code for the cron job is shown below:

```
    public function run_import(){
      if ( isset($_POST["run_import"])) {
        add_action( 'import_execution_event_test', array($this, 'run_execution_script' ));

        if(!wp_next_scheduled('import_execution_event_test')){
                    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_two_minutes', 'import_execution_event_test');
        }
      }
     include ( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'views/view-import.php' );
    }
```

Bear in mind here, I also have a custom schedule time here of every two minutes.

**This is the function that should be executed every two minutes:**

```
public function run_execution_script() {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://dev2.mydevs.co.uk/wp-cron.php?import_key=_GNIHMERsu&import_id=8&action=processing',  
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Test Curl Request',
        ));
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }
```

All the the method does is make simple curl request, this curl request does work if I call the method manually.

So to summarize, the cron even does appear in the wp cron schedule, it appears to be being triggered every two minutes as expected, but my curl request isn't functioning from the cron.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Could you show a bit more context around your add_action as well as run_execution_script? Also, not a big deal but you should be using `wp_remote_get()` instead of cURL directly.

Comment: Did you register `every_two_minutes` ?

Comment: @Sumit I did yeh, it now appears in the schedules array with the correct interval of 120 seconds

Comment: @kovshenin, thanks I've added some more context, I'll look in to wp_remote_get(); I didn't realize it existed.

Comment: You know that WP Cron is triggered by a website visit, so if you don't get any traffic within 2 minutes, it won't run?

Comment: @TomC, I have a slightly different configuration on this site where by a genuine server cron hits the wp-cron script every minute (the site gets quite low traffic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
if ( isset( $_POST["run_import"] ) ) {
    add_action( 'import_execution_event_test', ...
```

But when wp-cron.php is spawned, there's probably no POST variable called `run_import`, so your action is never added, and thus not triggered.

Comment: Ah OK, I think I have misunderstood how this works then. My understanding was the add action was only called once initially, I didn't realize it needed to be accessible each time the cron runs. I'll give this a switch around and retry. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, what happens during a cron run is pretty much `do_action( 'your_action' );` so if you have not added any callbacks to your action, then nothing's going to run.